# How To change the Tabbaritem Images dynamically In Iphone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am working  in One Iphone Application that has tabBarController with 4 tabs where each has different Image.
 The Image for each Tab would be in different color when selected   and should not be highlited .
That is generally its highlighted the selected tab.. I dont want this
can anyone help me 
Thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. There are some possibilities with use of private API's. But your app will fail at Apple's review.